# performing integration whit default limit?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have this assignment that I cant solve.

[image]

I have to solve this integral but I dont know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull the limit inside the integral.  Note that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left ( 1+\frac1{2 x} \right )^{x} = e^{1/2} $$

Comment: So when i tried to solve this, i got that aswell. But then i did not know how to calculate this with the limits p+5 and p-37 p->infinity. how do I solve that ? :)

Comment: You will be left with an integral of a constant.  Upon evaluation, the $p$'s cancel.

Comment: so I dont have do use the mean value theorem?

Comment: @JuliaRundström: apparently not.

Comment: Can you show me step by step solution ?

Comment: Because $p$ is large, and $x \in [p-37,p+5]$, then we may evaluate the above limit.  The integral becomes, in this limit, $$\int_{p-37}^{p+5} dx \, \left ( e^{1/2} \right )^5 = 42 \, e^{5/2}$$

Comment: @Julia: I would strongly recommend using the mean value theorem, to make it crystal clear *why* this procedure works. I don't think just saying "take the limit inside the integral" without motivation is enough (at least I wouldn't accept that if I would give this problem as an assignment in a basic calculus course). It's not just a matter of interchanging limit and integral, since you have $p \to \infty$ but inside the integral it suddenly becomes $x\to\infty$. With the mean value theorem you instead take something *out* of the integral and then take the limit on the outside.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you :)